# Set selected value of ng-options on $scope

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I want to get/set the selected index + offset of a dropdown on the scope.

So when I select the option called "Third " the `$scope.selectedIndex` value should be 3. But it's `obj3`.

Here's what I've come up with so far. I was hoping that `track by` would fix it, but it didnt :(

**Controller**

```
$scope.foos = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
```

**View**

```
<select data-ng-model="selectedIndex"
        data-ng-options="foo.name for foo in foos track by foos.indexOf(foo) + 1">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

**Generated view** (the generated value is as expected)

```
<select data-ng-model="selectedIndex" data-ng-options="foo.name for foo in foos track by foos.indexOf(foo) + 1">
    <option value="" class=""></option>
    <option value="1" label="First">First</option>
    <option value="2" label="Second">Second</option>
    <option value="3" label="Third">Third</option>
</select>
```

I can't use the array trick

```
ng-options="idx as choice for (idx, choice) in choices"
```

Because idx needs to be offset by `+1`

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/m9oqmGT8ZG5DDqLuXw7G?p=preview)

Comment: Please add plunker or fiddle

Comment: Plunker added. Seems there's more wrong with it then I assumed. Setting `selectedIndex = 1` doesn't select "First" as expected :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the value as name syntax:

```
data-ng-options="foos.indexOf(foo) + 1 as foo.name for foo in foos"
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/juFXFzlpXmWuS1ukde5R?p=preview

Comment: I thought I tried that :/, but it works -  thanks :)